# Controlled house ads

Tags: android, admob

I want to display house ads only. Basically, I have 5 different house ads and I want to control what I display (say users in certain geo should get ad1 and different geo should get ad2 and so on).

I thought about utilizing admob for this specifically but I have 2 questions.

1) Can I use admob solely for house ads?If not any existing solution I can use?
2) Can control which ad I can display? I can do the geo logic checking in my code but how can I say "display ad1"?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) I think you can use AdMob for this. I found a link that might help you.

[Google AdMob House Ads](https://support.google.com/admob/answer/3210442?hl=en)

2) AdMob allows you this functionality. So when you create the ads, you can specify this field

**Geo locations**: Select the geographic location you want to target

The link gives you details on this. Check it out.[Google AdMob House Ads](https://support.google.com/admob/answer/3049556?hl=en)

Comment: Thank you, what if I want to target users based on calculated paramaters (for example users whose user ID starts with letter A should be shown ad1). Can I show specific house ad from the code?

Comment: I'm not sure about how to make it that specific. You can contact the Google AdMob team and they may be able to help you better for this.